# Asymmetric random walk with unequal step size on real line

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, martingales, random-walk

Consider an asymmetric random walk $(X_n)$ in which the initial point is zero ($X_0 = 1$). It increases by $a$ with a probability of 0.3, remains the same with a probability of 0.4, and decreases by $b$ with a probability of 0.3, where $a<b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Also, suppose this process stops once $X_n \geq \lambda$.

To be more specific, say $a=0.3$, $b=0.5$, and $\lambda=1.4$. How can I calculate the probability of this process stopping? That is, what would be the probability of $X_n$ ever getting bigger than $\lambda=1.4$?

I found other problems with asymmetric random walks with equal integer step sizes. However, I am unsure if I can still use the same ways in the simple random walks on integer space.

Also, would it be a completely different problem in an environment where the step sizes are irrational numbers?

Comment: If the step sizes are rational multiples of each other, then you can scale everything up so that it's an asymmetric walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, at which point you have the usual situation with a recurrence relation. If they are not then things get a bit more complicated.

Comment: My final goal is to check an environment where the step sizes are irrational numbers. Would it be a completely different problem?

Comment: It's not fundamentally different, but it's definitely more complicated. Assuming of course that the increment has negative expectation. If it has positive expectation, or zero expectation with bounded values, then there's no real difficulty.